# A PAGE with plugin of top posts (wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I need a plugin for create "most visited posts" page.

NOT NEED ANY PLUGIN FOR A WIDGET, I WAN'T ANY WIDGET IN SIDEBAR.

I search a lot but I haven't found anythink.

Sorry for my english, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work: https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/display-posts-shortcode/

Just put the shortcode into the page you want the recent posts to show.